# tk.Toplevel window that comes up in wrong place

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to define a popup window with a combobox, which does something in the parent window.
It's more or less done (perhaps not the best way...), except that the popup window wouldn't come up in the right place: it would always show in the upper-left corner, even if the main window was elsewhere.
I suppose this behavior is to be expected from Toplevel windows.

Now, in order to make it show centralized with the main window and with the right size, I used `geometry` method on the popup window.
But for this to work, I have to apply the `update` method, so that the size of the window is known.
That gives me the popup window in the right place and with the correct dimensions.
However, another problem arises: the window shows up, in the upper-left corner, for a fraction of a second, before it shows in the right place.
This is certainly because the call of `update` is before the positioning and resizing.

Here's the code.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class PopupCombobox():

    def __init__(self, p_app, values):
        self.master = p_app.root
        self.parent = p_app
        self.gui = tk.Toplevel(self.master)
        # Drop the maximize button, and prevent to resize the window
        self.gui.resizable(width=tk.FALSE, height=tk.FALSE)
        self.gui.wait_visibility()
        self.gui.grab_set()
        self.gui.title("Pop up")
        self.gui.combo = ttk.Combobox(self.gui, values=values, width=15, state='readonly')
        self.gui.combo.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=8, pady=4)
        # self.gui.withdraw()
        self.gui.update()
        # self.gui.iconify()
        # self.gui.deiconify()
        self.centralize_widget()
        self.gui.combo.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.callback)

    def callback(self, event):
        self.parent.e.configure(text=self.gui.combo.get())
        self.gui.destroy()

    def centralize_widget(self):
        # (x,y) is the root upper-left corner
        x = self.master.winfo_x()
        y = self.master.winfo_y()
        # The width and height of the root
        w_master = self.master.winfo_width()
        h_master = self.master.winfo_height()
        # The width and height of the widget
        w = self.gui.winfo_width()
        h = self.gui.winfo_height()
        self.gui.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (w, h, x + (w_master - w)/2, y + (h_master - h)/2))


class App:

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.geometry("300x100+450+300")
        self.e = ttk.Label(root, text="text")
        self.e.grid()
        self.b = ttk.Button(root, text="Pop it up!", command=self.do_it)
        self.b.grid()
        self.choice = None

    def do_it(self):
        PopupCombobox(self, values=('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'))


win = tk.Tk()
app = App(win)
win.mainloop()
```

I tried with the commented methods `withdraw` before `update` and `iconify` or `deiconify` after.
With `deiconify` the observed behavior is exactly the same;
with `iconify` the program blocks.

There must be a better way.
Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So your issue seems to me that you can see sometimes the window initiating in the upper left corner and after that your code does what you like. Right?

Comment: @Atlas435 That's right. But it's not sometimes, it's always.

Comment: Try: `self.gui.attributes('-alpha', 0)` and add after that line: `self.gui.after_idle(lambda : self.gui.attributes('-alpha', 1))` and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: @Atlas435 and that is before, after or in place of `update`?

Comment: put `self.gui.update_idletasks()` instead of `self.gui.update()` in between the two recommended lines of code.

Comment: I tried with the `update` between your recommended lines, and it worked! I'll try that one too.

Comment: It has the same effect. Would you give that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem on my computer. It seems like it depends on system speed. But a solution can be:

```
self.gui.attributes('-alpha', 0) #makes window invisible
self.gui.update_idletaks() #get true values
self.gui.after_idle(lambda : self.gui.attributes('-alpha', 1)) #makes window visble again
```